# Accessing chef recipes contained in sub directories on github, from AWS OpsWorks

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, chef-infra, chef-recipe, aws-opsworks

I'm new to aws opsWorks and am trying to define a layer.

I would like to run custom Chef recipes within this layer, which are stored on my github. These recipes are contained within an existing "chef_repo" with the file structure :

```
git_repo
--------->chef_repo
------------------->.chef 
------------------->cookbooks
----------------------------->cookbook#1
----------------------------------------->recipe
----------------------------->cookbook#2
------------------->data_bags
```

However, opsWorks seems only to be able to access these recipes when they are placed in the root directory ie.

```
git_repo
---------->cookbook#1
---------------------->recipe
---------->cookbook#2
```

I do not want to changed the structure of my github repository, nor store a duplication of these recipes in a different github repository.

Is there anyway to apply these recipes to an aws-opsWorks layer, when they are stored like this??

Any ideas would be great. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know this isn't possible. You have to match the OpsWorks repository format exactly.

Comment: Is it not possible to use a "Berksfile" and chef 11.1 ??

Comment: Older chef versions are available if you configure it on your stacks, but the current default version is 12 and there is no Berks integration anymore.